# I can't make a colored QR Code with the qrcode library in Python

Tags: python

```
import qrcode
data = "Data"
qr = qrcode.QRCode(box_size=10, border = 3)
qr.add_data(data)
 
qr.make(fit = True)
img = qr.make_image(fill_color = 'red',
                    back_color = 'white')
 
img.save('QRCode.png')
```

As you can see, the fill color is set to be red. The data is correct when I scan it. But the QR Code that's generated is black and white. I don't know what to do. Almost every tutorial on the internet gives these lines of code. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It turns out I just didn't have Pillow module installed. I was pretty sure that I had it installed. But anyways, thanks to everyone for the comments and answers.

Comment: Python 3.9.0, copy/pasting your code works fine for me. What versions are you using?

Comment: I suspect you don't have the Pillow module installed, which `qrcode` normally uses to generate PNG images.  The module contains a fallback pure-Python implementation of PNG, but it looks like this doesn't support color or various other advanced features.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `make_image()` method only applies that attributes, if the `image_factory` parameter is set to `PILImage`.

In your code, you are setting the `image_factory` parameter to `StyledPILImage`.

To **change the fill color of the QR code**, you need to explicitly use the `SolidFillColorMask` module drawer.

```py
img = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage,
                    module_drawer=SolidFillColorMask(front_color='red'))
```